# Make two columns same height

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I tried to make two columns having the same height, but it was not.
[image]

My html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
   <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
   @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

   <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var divone = jQuery(".main-content").height();
        var divtwo = jQuery(".sidebar").height();
        var maxdiv = Math.max(divone, divtwo);
        jQuery(".main-content").height(maxdiv);
        jQuery(".sidebar").height(maxdiv);
    });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
@RenderBody()
<header>
    <h1>Document Heading</h1>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sermon", "Sermon", "Home")</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="main-content">

    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit...</p>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit...</p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

It is the asp.net mvc 4 _Layout.cshtml. The partial css is:

```
body {
font-size: .85em;
font-family: "Segoe UI" , Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #CCCCFF;
}


 .main-content
{
float: left;
width: 60%;
margin-left: 5%;
}

.sidebar
{
float: right;
width: 35%;
background-color: #00FFFF;
}

footer
{
margin: 0px;
clear: both;
background-color: #FF6600;
font-size: .8em;
text-align: center;
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Why the two columns have different height even they are enforced to be equal by jquery?

**Updated:**
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhshqzyc/CenND/)

Comment: Wheat does `console.log(maxdiv);` show?

Comment: No it didn't show. But it showed a value by alert(maxdiv).

Comment: could <h1> have different css properties in sidebar? Font looks a bit different. optical illusion?

Comment: No, it did not have a property.

Comment: Reproduce on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.Net/), where we can see, and adjust, the code.

Comment: Please see my updated js fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it by myself.

```
var divone = jQuery(".main-content").height();
var divtwo = jQuery(".sidebar").height();
var mainheight = $(window).height() - $('header').height() - $('footer').height();
jQuery(".main-content").height(mainheight);
jQuery(".sidebar").height(mainheight);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your div height is same. Please add a background color to the .man-content class for test purpose.

```
.main-content{
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    background-color: #006400; /*new*/
}
```

Comment: You are right, it seems the color was not overlapped. But the columns are hanged on the half way. How to change it.

Comment: You can remove the jquery code and do it through css please refer http://www.pagecolumn.com/liquidfixed/2_col_liquid_fix.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with jquery.

```
var column1height = $(column1).innerHeight();
var column2height = $(column2).innerHeight();
if (column1height > column2height){
  highestheight = column1;
}else{
    highestheight = column2;
}
$(column1).css('height',highestheight);
$(column2).css('height',highestheight);
```